# composition of a $\mathbb{Z}_p$-extensions and Hilbert class field extension (Iwasawa)

Tags: number-theory, galois-theory

I am reading Iwasawa's article *On $\Gamma$-extensions of algebraic number fields*. In paragraph 7.3 : " We now take as M the maximal unramified abelian $p$-extension of $L$ in $\Omega$ , i.e. the $p$-part of the Hilbert's class field over $L$; $M/K$ is then obviously a Galois extension. " with $\Omega$ an algebraic closure of $K$ and $L/K$ a $\Gamma$-extension (i.e. $Gal(L/K)=\Gamma \simeq \mathbb{Z}_p$ )

My question : Why is $M/K$ a Galois extension?

Thanks.

Comment: I misread your question, as you pointed out. Since I also don't see why it should be obvious that $M/K$ is Galois, I deleted my answer.

Comment: That's my fault, I am sorry, I made a mistake when copying the article. I edited my post.

Answer (score 2):

This is because of the maximal property of M : if *f* is any element of Gal(L/K) and if we extend it to a K-automorphism *g* of Omega, then *g*(M) is unramified over L since M is so, and *g*(M) will be contained in M because of the maximality of M; this means that M is stable by all the *g*'s, and this is one of the many equivalent conditions for M to be normal over K. You will notice that we did not use the particular form of Gal(L/K).